# What algorithm is used for generating default user icons?

Tags: discussion, gravatar, algorithm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How is the default user avatar generated?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17443/how-is-the-default-user-avatar-generated)

Geometric designs are automatically generated for each user. I know the designs are gravatars, but what is the algorithm they're generated with?

Comment: See http://gravatar.com. Also, belongs on meta.

Comment: It's called a gravatar and if you don't have one registered, I believe it uses your IP address to generate one.  Check http://gravatar.com.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gratuitous Friday afternoon analysis of Gravatar images used by page 1 of /users on MSO:

```
                        :    .    |    .    |
Photograph of a human   :*************** 15
Photograph of an animal :** 2
Cartoon of a human      :***** 5
Cartoon of an animal    :*** 3
Other cartoon           :* 1
Other abstract image    :*** 3
"Plain" Gravatar        :***** 5
Unknown (Possibly Jesus):* 1
```

Comment: Which is the "unknown"?

Comment: If I told you that would spoil the fun!

Comment: I think Pesto is the unknown...it's the closest one to being Jesusy.

Comment: Oh, I was looking at SO, not MSO. Whoops.

Comment: Fun, but doesn't answer the question in any way.

Answer (score 4):

Sadly, migrating this from SO means I can't close it as a dupe to those questions.  But [here is the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/392280/what-is-the-algorithm-used-to-generate-those-little-gravatar-identicon-images/392288#392288).