# How is the default user avatar generated?

Tags: support, faq, gravatar, profile-picture, identicon

Is there a name for the default avatars that are generated for users who do not assign one themselves and register using an authentication mode other than Google or Facebook?

Not the avatar of the blank user, but the one made up of shards, shapes, and colours:

[image] [image] [image] [image] [image]

Is there an online generator for something like that?

#### See also:

> [How do I change my profile picture, or avatar?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41277/how-do-i-change-my-profile-picture-or-avatar)

[Return to FAQ index](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/)

Comment: If someone has fears about security issues they should post it as a separate question.

Comment: This question is clean, simple and to the point. The site is already abound with overly long complicated FAQs that talk about every possible nuance and scenario imaginable. They're exhausting to read.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Well, that's what these FAQs are for and I like that we can get all the details if we want to. If you just want some general info, you would probably read it at Help Center.

Answer (score 147):

They're called [Identicons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identicon).

If you do not [upload your own image](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/01/announcing-a-new-way-to-change-your-profile-picture/) or register for your account using an authentication mode other than Google or Facebook, then Stack Exchange uses Gravatar and specifies Identicons as the default image:

- [Gravatar implementor's guide](http://en.gravatar.com/site/implement/)
- [How the URL is constructed](http://en.gravatar.com/site/implement/hash/), with:

  - When you're not registered (when Stack Exchange does not know your email address), this is based on your last known IP address so [might change when your IP address changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37762/how-does-an-identicon-identify-a-user/37763#37763)
  - For new users and those who click the "Identicon" in their profile, [Stack Exchange adds a salt if the user does not have a Gravatar account](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/204523/unexpectedly-changing-identicon/204540#204540), to make it a bit more secure. This only applies to new profiles created or identicons selected after November 2013 on the main sites (not on Area 51).
- [Original blog post by Don Park, the Identicons inventor](https://web.archive.org/web/20080703155519/www.docuverse.com/blog/donpark/2007/01/18/visual-security-9-block-ip-identification); their [implementation in Java](https://github.com/donpark/identicon) is available still.
- [Blog post by the creators of a PHP implementation of Identicons](https://web.archive.org/web/20200430104323/http://scott.sherrillmix.com:80/blog/blogger/wp_identicon/) as used by Gravatar.

Comment: It's not Gravatar who uses identicons as a default image. It's SO who chooses (with an URL parameter) to use identicon (instead of a standard image or monster-id.

Comment: So would it technically be possible to translate the image back to an md5, un-hash the md5, and retrieve a user's email address?

Comment: @MDXF The whole point of hashing algorithms is that they're supposed to be non-reversible.

Comment: @MDXF - you don't even have to translate the image itself (though that'd be somewhat trivial from what I understand of the image-generation alg.): the MD5 of the user's email is contained _right in_ the URL! Now, that said- I haven't found anyone successfully brute-forcing an email MD5 _from nothing_; but if you had anything to go on, then it'd be [somewhat doable](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/51514/8287) to fill out the email.

Comment: If then, why my current Stackoverflow avatar is not identical with the one generated from Gravatar using identicon (with my email address)?

Comment: Is [Scott Mix's `wp_identicon`](https://github.com/sherrillmix/wp_identicon/blob/master/wp_identicon.php) still *the* exact algorithm used by Gravatar?

Answer (score 46):

They are called [Identicons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identicon). The [Gravatar](http://www.gravatar.com) identicon image is based off of an MD5 hash of your email address.  Here is an [identicon implmentation](http://www.puls200.de/?p=316) if you are using .NET.  There are other implementations listed in the Wikipedia article as well.

**Important Update**
You may also be interested in [Unicornicons](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37328/my-godits-full-of-unicorns).

Comment: Gravatar use a hash of the email address, not the IP.

Comment: Good to know.  That makes sense for Gravatar since they have the email address.

Answer (score 19):

Checkout [Coding Horror](http://blog.codinghorror.com/identicons-for-net/), it has an algorithm based on IP Address similar to SO.

From [Wikipedia:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identicon)

> An Identicon is a visual
>   representation of a hash value,
>   usually of the IP address, serving to
>   identify a user of a computer system.
>   The original Identicon is a 9-block
>   graphic, which has been extended to
>   other graphic forms by third parties
>   some of whom have used MD5 instead of
>   the IP address as the identifier. In
>   summary, an Identicon is a privacy
>   protecting derivative of each user's
>   IP address built into a 9-block image
>   and displayed next the user's name. A
>   visual representation is thought to be
>   easier to compare than one which uses
>   only numbers and more importantly, it
>   maintains the person's privacy. The
>   Identicon graphic is unique since it's
>   based on the users IP, but it is not
>   possible to recover the IP by looking
>   at the Identicon.

Comment: Atwood's Law: That code has been ported to JavaScript: https://github.com/hgwr/identicon

Comment: Link on there is dead, there's an (I think) older version on CodePlex: http://identicon.codeplex.com/. There were some minor (Dispose) issues with it, so I've just uploaded a patch for this (and a little performance improvement).

Answer (score 10):

*As regards showing them automatically with Gravatar, here is the answer I posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/405717/how-to-auto-random-generate-the-gravatars-like-on-stackoverflow#405723):*

The 'random' colorful gravatars are displayed because this query string parameter is being added to every gravatar source url: `d=identicon`

This is done so that if the user doesn't have a gravatar image associated with his email, this 'random' image is displayed, instead of the default blue gravatar image.

The following displays the 'default' blue image because the parameter is not included:
[image]

Yet, the same url with the `d=identicon` parameter included, shows this:
[image]

*PS: This is the url used for the example: https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/94d093eda664addd6e450d7e9881bcad?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG*

Btw, these images (called [Identicons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identicon)) are not really random, but are generated based on a Hash of your IP address.