# Would it be possible to get different favicons per beta site?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, beta-phase, favicon

I don't know how many of these I plan to save, but I like to have all these sites on my bookmarks toolbar for easy access.

Surely I can't be the only one who works like this.

[image: The favicons all look the same in the browser's bookmarks]

Comment: Looking at the [list of sites in beta](http://area51.stackexchange.com/), I think each site's initials wouldn't cause a conflict right away if used as a temporary icon.  That might work until the sites get their own logos.

Comment: @Bill, that may work for now, but it doesn't seem like a tenable long- or even medium-term plan to me.

Comment: @Corey, your screenshot is making me want to play "how many sites can you identify solely from their favicons?"

Comment: @Popular:  It certainly won't work if there are dozens of sites in beta at the same time, but I doubt that many people will want to follow dozens of different beta sites anyway.  As the older sites get their permanent icons chosen, their initials will be freed up for new beta sites to use.

Comment: @Popular how many can you get? ;)

Comment: @Corey: I'm going to assume there's no larger resolution available than 640x360 even though I know there is, because it's more fun that way.  GameFAQs, YouTube, facebook, twitter, Hotmail, Gmail, MSO, SO, SU, SF, A51, six SE sites (Web Apps, Webmasters, Photography, Food and Cooking, Gaming and... Persian IT?), Coding Horror, The Daily WTF, Wordpress, Chowhound, LJ, xkcd, eBay and PayPal.

Comment: @Popular there's only 3 SE sites (2 per site, parent/meta), your list contains 2 of the 3. The Wordpress icon is just something that was never changed for a blog I read, and ...Chowhound? Never heard of it.

Comment: Bookmarks: tinypic, photobucket, youtube, facebook, twitter, some IPB forum, GMail, MSO, SO, SU, SF, area51, beta sites, coding horror, TDWTF, some WordPress blog, TVTropes, xkcd, ebay, paypal

Comment: Taskbar: Pidgin, Firefox, Skype, Windows notes, Paint

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Per the /faq on each SE 2.0 public beta:

> #### Why does this site look so “sketchy”?
>
> This site was created through the open
>   democratic process at Stack Exchange
>   Area 51, and it is currently in beta.
>   The site is still in the process of
>   being defined and constructed, so a
>   temporary placeholder design will be
>   used until the site is fully formed
>   and ready to leave beta. Once the site
>   is no longer beta it will have a logo,
>   domain, and design of the community's
>   choice -- see our meta-discussion site
>   if you have ideas or feedback!

Update: We now do custom sketchy letter icons for each site, like so:

[image]

Comment: +1 (now) - Thanks for implementing this **extremely** welcome improvement despite not indicating your inclination do to so as per your initial answer, any comment or the `status-planned` tag ;)

Answer (score 4):

The favicon is being used not only by bookmarks, but also by [browser extensions](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/djioipahfnmmhddmnanoicecpnfomned), the new [StackExchange.com/sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites), and many [StackApps](https://stackapps.com/questions/570/saggregator-a-way-to-accumulate-all-the-latest-activity-from-the-stackapps-api). With all of the smart people that are working on this I am sure they can come up with a way to differentiate the sites by using initials, colors, or [unicorns](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37328/my-godits-full-of-unicorns). Even just feeding Beta@cooking.stackexchange.com through the [Gravatar Identicons](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17443/how-is-the-default-user-avatar-generated) generator would be better than using the same icon for every beta site.