# Please don't share the [B] favicon for all SE 2.0 sites

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-exchange, favicon

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Would it be possible to get different favicons per beta site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58160/would-it-be-possible-to-get-different-favicons-per-beta-site)

Currently all SE 2.0 sites are using the same favicon during the beta phase.

[[B] http://sstatic.net/skins/sketchy/img/favicon.ico](http://sstatic.net/skins/sketchy/img/favicon.ico)

I know it stands for Beta, but it is hard to distinguish which site it refers to when all the beta sites can be mixed, e.g. in the https://stackexchange.com/ front page or in chat.meta.SO.

Could the letter B changed to some other character(s) that can represent the site more, before the community decides an official icon to use? e.g.

- "English Language and Usage" → [E],
- "Ubuntu" → [U],
- "Personal Finance and Money" → [$]

etc.

Comment: You're not the [only one that wants this.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58160/would-it-be-possible-to-get-different-favicons-per-beta-site)

Answer (score 1):

The beta period lasts 60-90 days; it is up to the community on that site to decide **during the beta** what their logo and favicon should be.

Per https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/

> **5. What should our logo and site design look like?**
>
> This one is pretty straightforward. Solicit contributions, throw out ideas, post preliminary (or finished) designs, and be supportive and respectful of other people’s ideas and creativity.
>
> We have designers on staff to come up with site designs but, if an idea stemming from the community stands out as exceptional, we are happy to use it.

Comment: I'm advocating a temporary *distinguishable* icon for each beta site, before the community can decide the actual icon to use.