# Related Accounts page - differentiation between beta accounts

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-exchange, beta-phase, icons

I'm a member of a number of Stack Exchange sites, including some beta sites, such as English or Photography.  As a shortcut to visit these pages, I often visit the 'accounts' (Related Accounts) tab on my profile, to get to other Stack Exchange sites. However, I'm part of 3 different beta sites, but I can't tell the different beta site boxes apart.  The three beta boxes have the same icon, whereas Stack Overflow, Super User, and Server Fault have their own icons, so I can tell which site I want to visit.  I have to *guess* what site, OR *remember* my rep score, which is hard for beta sites, because I'm not that involved yet, so they have similar scores.

**The point:** can we work on the Beta icons? perhaps add a name to the beta boxes until they leave beta and receive their own icons?

Comment: Was just going to ask this! +1 for saving me from typing it out on my phone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We now do custom sketchy letter icons for each site, like so:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can simply mouse over the gravatar to see the site in a tooltip.

[image: tooltip on related accounts page]

As for the rest, see the duplicate question:
[Please don't share the [B] favicon for all SE 2.0 sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60814/please-dont-share-the-b-favicon-for-all-se-2-0-sites/60823#60823)

Comment: I'm on a mobile browser a lot and can't see tooltips. I don't think they should be relied upon. Not the end of the world by any means though.