# How do I get a list of sites where I am a "beta user"?

Tags: feature-request

I feel like I must be missing something obvious, but I can't find a way to get a navigatable list of the beta sites where I have already registered.  The closest I've come is the "accounts" list on my profile, but that doesn't give me the opportunity to actually navigate to any of the sites listed.

Could someone educate me please?  Or take this as a feature suggestion if it doesn't exist.

Comment: Have you tried clicking on your name on the accounts page for the corresponding website's flair? This should link to your profile on the target site. And due to the new auto-login and auto-association, it should pretty much cover every site you register on the same OpenID. It's still not a "list of sites", but it is something of a middleman.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which profile are you talking about? If you've linked your accounts, you should be able to go to any SE site profile, click the flair for the site you want — all the sites you're registered with should be listed — and get taken to your profile on that site. From there, you can head to the site's main page or wherever you want to go. To quickly identify beta sites, just look for the <strike>big 'B'</strike> **EDIT: [site initials](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58160/would-it-be-possible-to-get-different-favicons-per-beta-site/60290#60290)** icon in the Sketchy theme.

Comment: I think you're giving the same answer that Grace Note gave in a comment above, which did work for me - go to my profile on the current site, check the 'accounts' tab, and it gives me the flair/links to go to the other sites where I am registered.  Thanks!

Comment: @Bruce, yeah, apparently so. We actually wrote our answers at roughly the same time, based on the timestamps. It seemed more like an answer than a comment to me, but... meh.

Comment: yeah, I liked both your answers, but since you (to paraphrase Jeopardy) posted your answer in the form of an answer, you get the credit.  *grin*

Answer (score 3):

The Area 51 page works fairly well for me:

> http://area51.stackexchange.com/?tab=progress&pagesize=50

It will show you which sites you are a beta user of.

Comment: That's an awfully big list to scroll through, and its just getting longer...