# Identicon generation algorithm

Tags: discussion, gravatar, profile-picture, identicon

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How is the default user avatar generated?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17443/how-is-the-default-user-avatar-generated)

Stack overflow uses a default generated image called Identicons for users. 
They look like this:

[image: one]
[image: one]
[image: one]
[image: one]

A basic overview of the system is [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17443/how-is-the-default-user-avatar-generated).

My question is, what is the algorithm that Gravatar uses to generate these? [The question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/392280/what-is-the-algorithm-used-to-generate-those-little-gravatar-identicon-images) provides a link to the original 9-panel version of identicons. Gravatar's version uses a 16-panel version.

Is the source available?

Comment: I think this actually makes more sense on SO than on Meta, but there's no option to migrate in that direction. EDIT: Turns out it's been [asked there](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/392280/what-is-the-algorithm-used-to-generate-those-little-gravatar-identicon-images) before

Answer (score 4):

I've found the PHP implementation for the 16-panel identicons.

http://scott.sherrillmix.com/blog/blogger/wp_identicon/

This has the PHP source for version 1.02.

Comment: Good find! Since we already have an FAQ entry about Identicons, I've added this link to the answer there.