# How are the default avatars generated on StackOverflow?

Tags: support, gravatar, profile-picture, identicon

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How is the default user avatar generated?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17443/how-is-the-default-user-avatar-generated)

https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=newest - how are the default avatars generated ?

Which algo is used ?

Comment: Should have been asked on meta, and anyway is a duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17443/how-do-you-generate-that-default-avatar-in-stackoverflow