# What factors determine my default avatar?

Tags: discussion, profile-picture

I know that my avatar is based on my email address, but how can I predict the kinds of shapes and the color of my avatar based on my email address?

What characteristics (characters, I assume) of the hash equal what shapes, colors etc?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How is the default user avatar generated?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17443/how-is-the-default-user-avatar-generated)

Comment: @popularDemand - Nope, I know that. The factor is my email hash. I want to know how that has is translated and what characteristics of the hash equal what colors, shapes etc.

Comment: Relevant link from the dupe: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identicon

Comment: @PopularDemand - NOT A DUPE!

Comment: @Pop: There's gotta be a better way - I spent a lot of time composing an answer only to discover that the question isn't original.

Comment: @GeorgeEdison - @Pop? hehe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way Gravatar works, the hash of your email address is used to form the parameters to their image generating function. These are passed to a special URL which returns an image:

**Example:**

> **Email:** bob@test.com
>   **Hash:** ebf3a1ca1e3ca553e2bd873b3cd96390
>   **URL:** http://gravatar.com/avatar/ebf3a1ca1e3ca553e2bd873b3cd96390?d=identicon

The default Gravatars for StackExchange are [Identicon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identicon) images (notice the `d` parameter in the URL above), so given your email hash and the function that generates the images, yes - you can predict what it will look like.

---

**Edit:** the source code for Identicon can be found here: http://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/wp-identicon.zip

Comment: I'd like to know how the image generating function works.

Comment: @Moshe: The source code is [here](http://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/wp-identicon.zip).

Comment: Please add to the answer.

Comment: @Moshe: I added it.

Comment: The MD5 hash is just used as the seed for the pseudo random number generator. At least that's how it works for MonsterId and Unicornify; I assume Identicons work the same way.