# On one page, same person, different reputation points

Tags: support, merge-accounts, multiple-accounts

Matt asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7366827/how-to-make-a-windows-slide-out-using-wpf-expression-blend-4and-c/7368888#7368888).

Matt answered that question (which isn't an answer). Both were joined before a week, so I assumed he's one person. They both have the same gravatar.

http://phpcode.eu/images/1315616380.php

- [Account 1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/928297/matt?tab=stats)
- [Account 2](https://stackoverflow.com/users/937474/matt?tab=stats)

And one more question - how did he do that? Two accounts, two email address ( = multiple OpenID's), right?

Comment: The second link is broken (404) - likely due to expiry of the domain.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> how did he do that? Two accounts, two email address ( = multiple openIds), right?

Both users are unregistered (it says "Unregistered User" at the top of their profiles), so they don't have OpenIDs. When he posted the question he filled out the Name/Email fields below the question body:

[image: Screenshot of the answer box]

Then he lost his cookie, so when he went to post an answer he filled them out again, creating a separate account

You don't really need to post a whole meta question when you see things like this; just flag the question for mod attention and let them know the accounts should be merged

Comment: okay, I'll remember that for the next time. sorry

Comment: @genesis No problem, it's not really wrong, just slow; I'm not sure how you ended up at -3

Comment: -1 now. I think these c++ room guys are still angry

Answer (score 3):

Well we know that the [gravatar is generated based off the email address](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17443/how-is-the-default-user-avatar-generated), and the 2 accounts are clearly separate (difference in rep, creation date, badges, tags, questions), so I would say your explanation is highly probable.

Two accounts with the same email address.

Comment: I think it's based off the Ip address

Comment: @genesis: [Nope, it's the email address](http://en.gravatar.com/site/implement/hash/).

Comment: It's IP if the user has no e-mail