# What is the arithmetic of generating face picture?

Tags: support, profile-page, gravatar, profile-picture, identicon

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How is the default user avatar generated?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17443/how-is-the-default-user-avatar-generated)

I found a interesting thing. That is, our original face picture is generated by an arithmetic which respects to email address. The design and color changes while the email address changes.

So my question is what is this arithmetic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called an [Identicon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identicon), and it's basically a pictorial representation of a hash of your data. (email or IP address at the time of registering)