# How is the default avatar for a new login created?

Tags: discussion, gravatar

I have always noticed the default login avatar for Stack Overflow is set to some random graphics image. How is this avatar created?

Comment: See also: [How is the default user avatar generated?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17443)

Comment: So, each "Identicon" is unique?