# How does SO assign thumbnail to user?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [what is the SOF algorithm for generating the icons for each user?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11526/what-is-the-sof-algorithm-for-generating-the-icons-for-each-user)

Like [image]

Comment: http://gravatar.com

Comment: Dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11526/what-is-the-sof-algorithm-for-generating-the-icons-for-each-user

Answer (score 0):

See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/392280/what-is-the-algorithm-used-to-generate-those-little-gravatar-identicon-images/392288#392288

Comment: So it's based on http://www.gravatar.com/.Is it free ? And what if that site is down?